# What's the reaction mechanism for the oxidation of primary alcohols (e.g. ethanol) to carboxylic acids using acidified KMnO4?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, redox

I've seen mechanisms for $\ce{MnO4-}$ in base reacting with primary and secondary alcohols to oxidise them, but what about $\ce{MnO4-}$ in acid?

All the ones I've found have either been referring to $\ce{MnO4-}$ in base or just showed the redox reaction occurring. I've been trying to look for one for a while now, but I still haven't found a satisfying one *(i.e. one that goes beyond showing the reaction in redox equation form).*

I hope anyone who knows anything about it can answer me on that, and as thoroughly as you can. Thanks.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4143/reaction-mechanism-for-oxidation-of-primary-alcohol-to-carboxylic-acid https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49542/mechanism-of-the-oxidation-of-alcohols-with-kmno4

Comment: also https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9001/difference-in-the-functioning-of-alkaline-and-acidified-kmno4 https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43283/mechanism-for-oxidation-of-primary-alcohols-to-carboxylic-acids but I don't see proper duplicate.

Comment: I was looking for a mechanism specifically about acidified KMnO4. I can't seem to find one very easily, not even here on Stack Exchange. I hope someone has an answer for it.

Comment: Well, it looks like doesn't it? And it's not particularly strange, redox mechanisms are notoriously obscure and often debatable. Even if you find it there's high probability it's more or less wrong.